# Асинхронное шифрование

Tags: шифрование, php, rsa, c++

Подскажите алгоритм для одностороннего шифрования. Нужно сделать, чтобы программа общаясь с сервером была уверена, что он настоящий. Нужен абсолютно простой алгоритм, который можно быстро реализовать на с++ и php.
Или таких алгоритмов нет и нужно брать готовые решения на основе RSA?

Comment: А чем вам не нравится https (по модулю доверия к центрам сертификации)?

Comment: а RSA и есть очень простой алгоритм. прекрасно расписанный в куче источников.